# Posts and Pages w. private visibility don't show up in existing content

Tags: posts, content, private

when I create or edit a link in the editor (post or page) pages & posts with private visibility don't show up in the "existing content" section of the "insert/edit link" popup. All pages/posts with public visibility are shown.

Is there a fix for that behavior? This doesn't make sense as I have all necessary privileges to see and edit these private pages/post.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Heiner

Comment: Close-voted as *off-topic*. What you're describing sounds like a *bug*, and as such should be [reported to Trac](http://trac.wordpress.org).

Comment: I've reported this as bug. Really incredible that no one has reported this before! What are all the wp users doing with their installation!? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update: This bug has already been in the Trac for a long time, but isn't fixed! There is a workaround though. Use the Plugin PressPermit or hack the core as explained here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/20114/20114.diff

Comment: @Heiner Please write your solution as an answer and mark the question as _answered_.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution pulled out of the comments:*

> This bug has already been in the Trac for a long time, but isn't fixed! There is a workaround though. Use the Plugin [PressPermit](http://presspermit.com/) or hack the core as explained here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/20114/20114.diff